# convert a list containing sublist and tuples into a flat list

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, lambda

'a = [1,2,[12,5,(6,7,9)],[34,56]]
lambda l: [item for sublist in l for item in sublist]

ab = lambda a: [item for sublist in a for item in sublist]

print(ab(a))'

I want output like this [1,2,12,5,6,7,9,34,56]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enjoy:

```
def convert(lst):
    if all(not isinstance(e, (list, tuple)) for e in lst):
        return lst[:]
    else:
        result = []
        for e in lst:
            if isinstance(e, (list, tuple)):
                converted = convert(e)
                result.extend(converted)
            else:
                result.append(e)
        return result
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer..   But I posted some another version to solve... Please give your comments.....

Comment: Where did you post it?

Answer (score 0):

I treat this  as a text processing job.First convert the pass-in list into the string representation, then split the string into small parts each contains a element, finally i use a empty list receive these fresh elements.Here is my code snippt:

```
def simpleL(complexL):
    a =repr(complexL).split(',')
    c=[]
    for i in a:
        element =i.strip('[()] ')
        if element.isdigit():
            c.append(int(element))
    return c
```

Answer (score 0):

```
output = []
def uni_lst(lst):
    if type(lst) in [list, tuple]:
        for x in lst:
            if type(x) in [list, tuple]:
                uni_lst(x)
            else:
                output.append(x)
    return output
```

Above code will make a single list from any type of list or tuple.

Comment: As far as I see, it works but there're some disadvantages I find. First, it's better to check the instance using `isinstance` build-in function like this: `isinstance(lst, (list, tuple))` instead of `type(x) in [list, tuple]` (see PEP8 for details: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). Another disadvantage is the use of the global object `output`, a good function has to do all operations inside.